# Are remote jobs done for Canadian clients worth points for Express Entry?

Tags: express-entry

As a software developer, I have often worked for Canadian clients and companies but remotely from my home country. I do have their payment proofs, contracts and reference letters. Will this be counted as CANADIAN EXPERIENCE and granted points in express entry profile?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not count based on a statement on this [Canadian government website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/canadian-experience-class.html):

- have at least 1 year of skilled work experience **in Canada**, in the last 3 years before you apply. The work was:

  1. full-time or
  2. an equal amount in part-time
- have gained your work experience by working in Canada legally